# Changing max-height in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I wanted to change the max-height in the navbar in mobile version. 
This following code-snippet is in the bootstrap.css file

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
   .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
     max-height: 340px;
   }
}
```

I have a custom .css file where I already successfully changed some properties of the navbar. To change the max-heigt from 340px to auto I wrote the following:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #DBFAFF
  }
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus  {
    color: #40F99B
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: auto;
  }
}
```

the first two changes are working.

And my in my HTML file is the following line:

```
<nav class="navbar-custom navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
```

But this doesn't change the max-height to auto. When I'm changing the 340px in chrome inspect it does exactly what I want.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So quick research found out that you can change these variable at this site:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

@navbar-collapse-max-height

or else with LESS

Answer (score 1):

Use `height:auto;` or use `!important` may be it's help you.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #DBFAFF
  }
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus  {
    color: #40F99B
  }
  .navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: auto;
    height:auto; /* Add this */
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Maybe I should add, that when I was changing 340px to auto in chrome inspect it was the following:

navbar.less:661
`navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 340px;
}`

Comment: `.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
      .navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse` remove space in `navbar-cutom` and `navbar-fixed-top` i think it's work, check update answer

Comment: then please make a working fiddle to give you better suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS Selector is incorrect : 
you should delete the space character among `.navbar-custom` and `.navbar-fixed-top` !

and write : 
`.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top`

Comment: there is an another mistake that i found it now !

Comment: there is an another mistake that i found it now !
the bootstrap styles is for : min-width: 768px
and your styles is for : max-width: 767px
please change your range to bootstrap range or Conversely ...

Comment: Ur welcome
Excuse me if i can't write English language very well ...
because i'm from iran and new to English language ! :)